# Integral of fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+x^8}$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

How to calculate $\int\mathcal{F}\left( \frac{1}{1+x^8} \right)$?
Are there special hits using the fact that it's Fourier transform?

Comment: Residuet theorem finishs this one fast

Answer (score 2):

Defining the Fourier transform as
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{- 2\pi i x \xi}\,dx, 
$$
and the inverse transform as
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\hat f(x)\}=f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\xi)\ e^{2 \pi i \xi x}\,d\xi
$$
you have that
$$
f(0)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(\xi)\,d\xi
$$
and then
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal F\left\{\frac{1}{1+x^8}\right\}\,d\xi=\left.\frac{1}{1+x^8}\right|_{x=0}=1
$$
Using the definition $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{- i x \xi}\,dx$ or $\hat{f}(\xi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ e^{-  i x \xi}\,dx$, you'll find $2\pi$ or $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: I want to find $\int \hat{f}dx$.
Not $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f} dx$

Comment: do you mean the indefinite integral $\int \hat f(\xi)\mathrm d\xi$?

Comment: Yes.
Sorry for misunderstanding.